# setTimeout behave differently in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

I have jquery animation which is working fine only on firefox but now on chrome and Internet explorer. This is [my Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1qjzfuf/).

```
setTimeout(function() {$('#wheel-l').fadeIn(1000);}, 3300);
setTimeout(function() {$('#wheel-r').fadeIn(1000);}, 3300);
```

I am using setTimeout for the animation. The wheels are still spinning when the car disappears. In firefox the animations are working fine but in chrome and IE the wheels keep spinning. Can anyone tell me how to fix this. I have tried to change the timeout values but it is not fixing. I am not great in jquery and wasted whole of my day on this but could not figure out. Please someone can tell me how to fix this that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can anyone help me please

Comment: I dont see any problem...I am using IE11

Comment: The wheel is keep spinning after the car is disappeared